# Why is Resume from Sleep sometimes 5-10 seconds and other times 1+minutes?

Tags: suspend

Sometimes, when i resume from sleep (otherwise known as opening my laptop lid, after putting it to sleep by closing it), it takes only 5-10 seconds or even less to come back to a password prompt.

Other times, like just now, it took closer to a minute to actually come back.  I've seen it take close to two minutes to get back from a black screen.  I used to think when this occurred that the computer froze or otherwise ceased funcitoning in sleep mode and I then hard powerred off, now i've learned patience.

Is this because it's going into suspend-to-disk mode perhaps rather than suspend-to-ram?  I am always plugged in, or usually such, when this happens, so i don't think it would have to suspend to disk.

Also, if it is suspend to disk that is causing this, perhaps a 'resuming' message could come on the screen to give me an indication what is going on?

Thanks for any guidance on how i can resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

Closing the lid will cause the machine to suspend to RAM. After you resume you can look at the kernel messages to see what part of the resume is taking so long.

For example:

```
dmesg | grep "PM: resume"

[   60.006935] PM: resume of drv:hub dev:1-1:1.0 complete after 177.408 msecs 
[   60.006945] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_00 complete after 177.306 msecs
[   60.006953] PM: resume of drv:usb dev:1-1.4 complete after 172.034 msecs 
[   60.006985] PM: resume of drv: dev:ep_81 complete after 177.417 msecs 
[   60.162766] PM: resume of drv:scsi dev:host1 complete after 334.403 msecs
```

you may be able to observe a device in the log that is taking too long to resume, which could be the root cause.  I suggest filing a bug against the "linux" package.